# Creating Fancy dialog and window in C++

Tags: c++, graphics

I wants to make a GUI application with some fancy graphics, like flipping the window, creating translucent window on window/Linux platform.
What will be the steps for these, if I am using window/linux platform and C++ programming language using wxWidget or Juce. 
As I know idea how to create such window, But i have some knowledge about wxWidget and Juce.

Thanks!

Comment: This question is overly-broad. Try asking about one platform and widget toolkit.

Comment: If such effects do not have an actual purpose but are just for additional eye-candy, I suggest to avoid them: usually it's much better to go just with the "normal" theme provided by the Window Manager, if the user wants glossy borders and flipping windows he can enable these functionalities system wide (Aero, Compiz) by itself. 90% of "custom skinned" applications would only benefit in usability if they just sticked to the system theme that the user chose.

Comment: @karlphillip I will keep in mind about this and strictly follow it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On wxWidgets, I found an interesting [message](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.wxwindows/browse_thread/thread/ed2941d344137db0/8f14b0087956b84c) that states:

> Since **wxFrame** (which is usually the class you use for the main application),
>   is derived from **wxTopLevelWindow**, you can use `wxTopLevelWindow::SetTransparent(int alpha)` method, where: an *alpha*  value of **0** sets the window to be fully transparent, and a value of **255** sets the window to be fully opaque.

There's a [demo available here](http://www.zaachi.com/cs/items/wxwidgets-transparent-window.html) that seems to use this technique (search for [Alpha.zip](http://zaachi.com/up_others//Alpha.zip)). I was able to compile it with:

```
g++ AlphaApp.cpp AlphaMain.cpp GUIDialog.cpp -o alpha `wx-config --libs` `wx-config --cxxflags`
```